# "managed" depends on "manager" structure

Tags: java, design-patterns, structure

I have a structure problem with DependancyInject.

***Situation***

I'm working on creating a server for a voxel based game; it's entirely modulated, but the relevant modules are the following 3.

NetworkModule(sends and receives packets)
WorldModule(Handles world related events and stores worlds)
World(Stores all the blocks and has a list of players in the world)
Block(Has a material, and some other fields)

***Problem***

When the setMaterial(Material material) method is called in the Block class, a "BlockChange" packet should be sent to all the players in the world to let the client know that the block has changed type. To send that packet, the Block class must have access to the NetworkModule. There is an instance of NetworkModule stored inside the WorldModule. Technically this can be easily solved, just pass the WorldModule, or NetworkModule into each Block class. To me that rings alarm bells, it ties the manager to the managed and also wastes space saving that instance. I feel like there must be a better way to do this such that they don't depend on each other.

Comment: Implement a static in-memory event publisher. The `Block` class will use that static event publisher to publish the `BlockChange` message, another part of the software will listen to it and republish it on the network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered adding a "Message Bus" module to your game?

Basically, you want to send messages around between your components and not have them coupled with each other. This is the aim of the [Mediator Pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/mediator).

You could create topics to which your components subscribe to in order to get status updates. Your components could also publish to this topics to notify the other components that its status has changed.

I'll not enter in the details of code because I do not have much time right now, but here are some ideas:

- Your `Mediator` object should hold a map whose keys are the "topics" and the values are lists of "subscribers"
- Whenever a message is published in a specific topic, all subscribers should be notified
- Your components will "subscribe" to the relevant topics of the `Mediator` in order to receive updates from the other.
- Your components should be aware of your `Mediator`. This should be the only mean of communication between them. When a component status change, it should notify the others by publishing a message on a specific topic (let's say "BlockChange").
- This message doesn't need to be necessarily pure text. It could be a proper object, containing all relevant data that will allow the other components to be aware of the changes. This message could even include a reference to the object that has changed itself.

This are some general ideas, let's see if you can get somewhere from here...

Comment: The server itself does use this event system I made, http://bit.ly/1TopBg8 (A global static event handler) and http://bit.ly/1OwKurn (The main server class has an instance of this). I don't know why I didn't think of using it hahah. Thank you much! I think I will take your advice and separate my modules as much as possible, start using my event system as a Mediator instead of an update poster for external modules.